# Find Parent Class from a recurring List<class>

Tags: c#, wpf, list, mvvm

I have a class like below,

```
public class Folder : BindableBase
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value;  }
    }
    private List<Folder> subfolders=new List<Folder>();
    public List<Folder> Folders
    {
        get { return subfolders; }
        set{ subfolders= value; }
    }
}
```

This class is binded to a `TreeView` `HierarchicalDataTemplate`
When i select any node from the `TreeView` i will get the `SelectedItem` as `Folder class object`. How do i find the parent classes for the `SelectedItem` in `View Model`.

**HierarchicalDataTemplate**

```
  <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="Folders" ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                
            <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </StackPanel>
  </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties will bubble up and be exposed since that's how C# inheritance works. Just bind to base properties directly as if they live on Folder.

```
public class BindableBase
{
    public string InheritedName { get; set; }
}

public class Folder : BindableBase
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value;  }
    }
    private List<Folder> subfolders=new List<Folder>();
    public List<Folder> Folders
    {
        get { return subfolders; }
        set{ subfolders= value; }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding InheritedName}" />
```